# Can PHP object can destruct itself on construct?

Tags: php, oop, constructor, destructor

Can `function __construct()` destruct itself after construction?

Like in following pseudo-code, and if yes than how to do it:

```
function __construct() {
  if($something) echo "OK!"
  else __destruct();
```

}

Comment: -1 Have you tried it?

Comment: Can it destruct itself?

Comment: 1) have you tried it? 2) why would you even need to manually call `__destruct()`? 3) WHY!?!?! 4) Wut? Why?

Comment: To free memory. Yeah I tried `Fatal error: Call to undefined function __destruct() in...`

Comment: Why do you need to free memory? Have you actually tested something? I would start here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Comment: to free memory? Then dont instantiate the object in the first place... takes one `if` statement for that

Comment: @PeeHaa why? simply because i find invalid inputs in the `__construct($input)` parameter, and thus do not want to initialise the class in the first place.

Comment: Jusr `throw` up in that case @ulkas

Comment: You may be able to do this, but your syntax is wrong, the call would be $this->__destruct();  You're getting "undefined function" errors because inside the function of a class the other class functions are not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Method `__destruct` is a magic method in PHP and must not be called manually.

Hovewer it does not do any real magic, the name of the method should be something like `onDestructed` or so, just like an event listener.

So, `__destruct` is called when there are no more references to the object. The implementation of method could be the following:

```
function __destruct(){
  echo "An object of class " . __CLASS__ . " has been destroyed " ;
}
```

And to answer your question, yes, it can be called explicitly, and you will just execute the code inside method `__destruct`, but you will not destroy the object (unless you do some real garbage collection inside it).

```
function __construct($something) {
  if($something) 
    echo "OK!" ;
  else 
    $this->__destruct(); // $this-> must be used here!
}
```

To destroy it, you can use `unset($object)` or just set it to null in some cases.

Comment: Thank you. Does having no reference to object can be done with `unset`? Are they other ways of removing object? Im afraid that my poor OOP skills will suffocate memory so that am just in case removing all objects I dont need later.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an instance of our Object with $test = new YourObject(), it would not be possible anymore to return an instance of it into $test, when you destruct it right away...

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the condition to determine whether the object gets constructed:

```
   if($something) {
   $object = new Class();
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you destroy the object in constructor then u can achive your require ment like below.

```
class class1
{
    function __construct()
    {
        print "constructor\n";
        print "Now destructor going to call\n";
        unset($this);
    }
    function __destruct()
    {
        print "this is destructor\n";
    }
}
$obj=new class1;
```

In the above example .
While creating object it will call the constructor then constructor 
function destroy itself by unset function then destructor function called and
object also destroyed.